# How to connect Odoo Webservice using Swift3

Tags: web-services, swift3, odoo, xml-rpc

I'm newbie to IOS app, my requirement is to show all customer from odoo into IOS page. How can i connect the odoo XML-rpc API in Swift3.

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/api_integration.html

Can anybody give me an idea to connect XML-rpc connection (odoo) in Swfit3 code ?

Comment: I just need any idea to call XMLRPC API in swift3 to procedd

Comment: Just look for a library. If you're trying to call the web api of newer Odoo versions, you could also look for JSON RPC libraries.

Comment: Have you find any solution for this ? I need to connect same odoo webservice using swift. Please help me if you have any solution